# Show divider after the last item in the list

Tags: android, android-listview, divider

I added a divider drawable to my listview but it appears for all the items except after the last item.

I only have 5 items on the list, so its all white space after the last item, i want to have a divider even after the last item

i tried this:

```
android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
```

in my listview. But it didnt work

Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try following in XML

```
<View
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/YOUR_LIST_ID" />
```

Comment: It's Not a Correct Way @Chintan Raghwani

Answer (score 8):

Horizontal line

```
<View
android:id="@+id/view"
android:background="#FF4500"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2dp"     
android:layout_below="@+id/listview_id" />
```

vertical line

```
 <View
android:id="@+id/view"
android:background="#FF4500"
android:layout_width="2dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"     />
```